ClickOnce installer fails attempting to fetch the application manifest
I have a ClickOnce installer which has been signed with a valid certificate and deployed to the web server. It's an older project I've had to pick up and was previously working before the certificate expired.
When I install the application directly through the application manifest, it installs no problem and shows the correct publisher and certificate.
When I attempt to install the application through the setup.exe, I get

An error occurred trying to download 'https://my-deploy-url.com/app.application'

When I check the install log:

URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697202'

I've checked internet options is configured to have Warn if changing between secure and not secure mode disabled. I've tried adding the domain to trusted sites. I can get it to install using rundll32 dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication https://yourdomain.com/yourapp.application. It just doesn't want to install at all from the setup.exe no matter what I try.
Any ideas greatly appreciated.
